# Why Summernote text editor value return empty ? (Vue Js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, summernote

I am using Summernote TextEditor and whenever i submit my form it returns empty result. I shared my code, below.

> Vue Component

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div id="summernoteExample" :v-model="page.content">
   </div>
</div>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'PageCreate',
    data() {
        return {
            page: {
                content:''
            },

        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitPage(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.page.content); // Return Empty Result in console
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How i get my value from that TextEditor Or anyone have any better suggestion ?

Comment: It happended for me also and I also looking a solution for this. I tried in both ways as with pure jQuery out of Vue's scope (by document.ready function) and inside of vue's mounted function but not succeeded.